# monthrange python function equivalent in R

Tags: python, r, function, equivalent

Hello I am trying to set up my code to accept data from an API I will be pulling. The code has already been written in python and I am trying to recreate it but in R. Here is the python code:

```
month = 'may'.lower()
year = '2023'
d_month_numeric = {
    'january': 1,
    'february': 2,
    'march': 3,
    'april': 4,
    'may': 5,
    'june': 6,
    'july': 7,
    'august': 8,
    'september': 9,
    'october': 10,
    'november': 11,
    'december': 12
}
month_num = d_month_numeric.get(month)
month_begin = f'{int(year)}-{month_num}-1'
month_end = f'{int(year)}-{month_num}-{monthrange(int(year), month_num)[1]}'
month_end_plusone_dt = pd.to_datetime(month_end) + dt.timedelta(days=1)
month_end_plusone = str(month_end_plusone_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

This is what I have written out so far in R:

```
month= " "
    year=" "
    d_month_numeric = c('january'= 1,
    'february'=2,
    'march'= 3,
    'april'= 4,
    'may'= 5,
    'june'= 6,
    'july'= 7,
    'august'= 8,
    'september'= 9,
    'october'= 10,
    'november'= 11,
    'december'= 12)

    month_num= get("d_month_numeric")[month]
    month_begin = c(as.integer(year)- as.integer(month_num)-1)
```

This code seems to run without error in Rstudio but I cannot figure out what functions I need to use in R to recreate the month range part of the python code, let alone the pd.to_datetime etc etc equivalent functions in R.

This is an example output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, vasiliki panagis! Your question seems to contain some stack-interface-garbage ("your text" and such); I think it's clear what it might be, could you please [edit] your question and fix it? There are some misplaced backticks that are likely not in your real code.

Comment: It would help to have sample data, including input and its expected output. Thanks!

Comment: As-is, someone who knows both Python and R may be able to help you. If you explain what `monthrange` does and show what output your hoping for, then people who only know R will be able to help.

Comment: @r2evans thank you! I am sorry, it is clear I am new to SO! I will edit the question code now.

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you for the response! from my understanding this is what the monthrange python function accomplishes:   monthrange(year, month) :- This function returns two integers, first, the starting day number of week(0 as monday) , second, the number of days in the month.

Comment: @r2evans I am pulling data using an API from a software program called Wiski. From there the python code generates monthly graphs of temporal data (water quality monitoring). This part of the code is in the very beginning, before it even pulls the data using the API. From what I understand the original writer of the code was setting up dataframes to store the data once it is pulled from the API.

Comment: I agree with GregorThomas' recommendation to provide an explanation. Ff you provide sample input and expected output from the R equivalent, we will have a better idea. I'm trying to run this in python but `monthrange` is not defined here. Please provide the output from python so at least we can infer something from here. (I fixed the code in your question, it was still a parsing error.)

Comment: @r2evans of course! I just added an example output of one of the graphs the python code creates..

Comment: Interesting. I think you're asking how to produce the data output of a python function, but you added the picture of a rich matplotlib call or similar. Is `monthrange` not a "simple" function that takes a couple of arguments and returns a list, dictionary, scalar, or something "just data"?